# data.table - removing all groups with unequal count in R

Tags: r, count, duplicates, data.table, unique

I want to group my data.table by ID and remove all groups where the `count` does **not** have the same value across the years.

Maybe something along the lines that if ID and count combination is not unique, remove all rows with that ID?

I am looking for a solution suitable for large data.table

DATA:

```
# example data
ID <- c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 6), rep("C", 2), rep("D", 3), rep("E", 4))
count <- c(rep(3, 5), rep(4, 6), rep(1, 2), c(1,3,3), rep(1, 4))
year <- as.numeric(c(rep(c(2012, 2013, 2014, 2015), 4), 2012, 2013, 2015, 2016))
mydata <- cbind(ID, year, count)
mydata <- as.data.table(mydata)
mydata <- setorder(unique(mydata))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure this is the most elegant solution, maybe somebody has a better one. In the meantime:

```
mydata[, k := length(unique(count)), by=ID][k==1][,k:=NULL]
```

EDIT:
Copying from the link above, the proper solution:

```
mydata[ , if(uniqueN(count) == 1) .SD, by = ID]
```

Comment: well, better than what i came up with

Answer (score 1):

I actually found an answer to my question:

```
 q <- which(duplicated(mydata[,c('ID','year')]))
  if(length(k) > 0){
    prob <- mydata[k, ID]
    mydata <- mydata[!ID %in% prob]
  }
```